# Error: Database table jobs for model Job was not found

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, xampp

I saw everything about this topic on Stack Overflow but nothing really solved my issue.

I migrated an app made on cakephp from a linux machine to a w7 machine. I'm not a programmer so I'm not familiar with this kind of thing. Btw, I installed xamp on this new machine, imported everything but on running in localhost one part of the app display this error.

> Warning (2): mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php, line 370]
>       Warning (2): mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php, line 375]
>       Warning (2): mysql_get_server_info(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php, line 383]
>       Warning (2): mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php, line 407]
>
> Missing Database Table
>
> Error: Database table jobs for model Job was not found.
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\views\errors\missing_table.ctp``

I've done a new installation of phpmyadmin to manage my db, I've imported the previous tables and so on, but the error is still there.
That's not a problem of plural terms, or missing tables, table is there with the exact name in the exact db!

Model name-->job.php  controller --> jobs_controller.php

This is my database.php code:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    var $default = array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'seo',
        'prefix' => '',
    );

    var $test = array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'test_database_name',
        'prefix' => '',
    );
}
?>
```

Cache is clean.

This is the .htaccess (may this could block phpmyadmin connection)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   Rewriterule ^phpmyadmin/.*$ - [PT]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm really stuck with this, sorry for my length.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: did you set the right password for the BD user?

Comment: Well that's the problem. I'm not sure how could i do that. i've imported this sql file on phpmyadmin:                                                                      CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost';
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD( 'xxx' ); 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `seo` . * TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION ;

Comment: set the password correctly for the user root, and make sure the user has the correct priveledges to access the database

Answer (score 0):

Try whit password empty

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'seo',
    'prefix' => '',
);

var $test = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'test_database_name',
    'prefix' => '',
);
```

}
?>